# huffman without using node

Tags: java, compression, nodes, huffman-code

I'm thinking on possibility of making a Huffman code without "node".
It's based on the nodes then my question seems a bit ambiguous.
I know,maybe we have to use string's abilites ...

Is it possible ? and if "YES" how Is it possible in java? 
Thanks.

Comment: did anyone understand this?

Comment: i did understand he doesn't like nodes

Comment: i'm thinking on a faster and more simple way, my intention. and i have no reason to make my mind it's impossible.

Comment: Man, SO should make a new badge for Comedians. this guys is taking this to a whole new level when it goes from `i must get it's answer to know more in the life` to `maybe we have to change the original algorithm`

Comment: i'm serious. i asked a logic question.

Comment: Analogy of your questions . It is possible ==> Is it possible to cure common cold , yes ,no , maybe we shall never no unless someone actually finds a cure. question 2 ==> if yes how ==> again only when someone actually finds a cure. Java/other pgm ==> first you need the algorithm.

Comment: This link has good info about different compression algorithm and then how they compare ==>  http://www.ijcse.com/docs/IJCSE10-01-04-23.pdf

Comment: Raj , your comment is ambiguous. "YES , then it's the way..." or "No,bro. forget it." is my answer. no need to wasting more  words. Thanks for that Link. but i'm familiar to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use indices instead of nodes but you need somewhere nodes and/or vertices.